# diff implementation in Java

Tags: java, diff

I'm looking for a diff implementation in Java. I've seen that Python has its own SequenceMatcher (with difflib), which is exactly what I need... in Java.

Is there any portage? Or is there any other class/library that performs the same in Java?

If not, where can I find the source code of that difflib (if free as in speech) to make my own implementation of SequenceMatcher in Java ?

Unfortunately, Apache Commons Lang doesn't help me much.

Thanks!

Comment: https://java-diff.dev.java.net/ http://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utills/ http://www.incava.org/projects/java/java-diff/

Comment: @Bozho all links is out of date

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This library seems to be what you're after: [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/).

It has the following main features:

1. **Diff:** Compare two blocks of plain text and efficiently return a list of differences.
2. **Match:** Given a search string, find its best fuzzy match in a block of plain text. Weighted for both accuracy and location.
3. **Patch:** Apply a list of patches onto plain text. Use best-effort to apply patch even when the underlying text doesn't match.

In case you want an alternative, you could also try this: [java-diff-utils](http://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/)

Comment: Exactly what I needed: diff, match and patch.

Comment: github fork of java-diff-utils: https://github.com/KengoTODA/java-diff-utils

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can run a MR job which can use https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/ to do the required job. I dont feel there are any tools out of the box to do your job.